# ¿Cómo dejar un tamaño estático el tamaño de un código QR hecho con phpqrcode?

Tags: php

Buen día a todos.

Espero que todo se encuentren bien, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Quisiera saber si es posible dejar estático el tamaño de un código QR generado con phpqrcode, sin importar el tamaño del contenido. He buscado mucho pero no encuentro nada.

Estoy creando un código qr usando phpqrcode, al cual le estoy dando un tamaño estático.

```
QRcode::png($contenido, $filename , $nivel, $tamaño, 2);
```

En esté caso la variable $tamaño es igual a 8.

El tema es que entre más grande sea la cadena de texto de la variable $contenido el qr se va haciendo más grande.

Y lo que quisiera lograr es que sin importar el tamaño de la cadena de texto el código qr se pudiera quedar de un tamaño fijo.

Sí alguien sabe cómo o si tiene alguna liga de información se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios, he modificado mi pregunta para ver si así es más clara la situación, agradecería mucho cualquier tipo de ayuda.